# File transfer in ad hoc network

Tags: file-transfer, ad-hoc-network

I'm trying to transfer files within ad hoc network. Is there any other way that I can transfer files since I've tried homegroup and apps such as AirDroid, ShareIt and MoveIt. I'm using Windows 10 and looking forward to send files from my laptop to smartphone (Android).

Answer (score 0):

File managers such as [Total Commander](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ghisler.android.TotalCommander) and [Solid Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.solidexplorer2) can connect to shared files and folders over LAN. You need to create a shared folder on your PC and apply appropriate permissions (Write&Read if you are going to send files from your phone to pc). Then use one of the file managers to connect to that folder.